# Remove SliverAppBar bottom border - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I wanna remove the border that I highlighted in the above picture. I couldn't find any solution to fix this :(

here is my SliverAppBar Code :

```
NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, isScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
               SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text('Applying to this job opportunity'),
                  pinned: true,
                  titleSpacing: 0,
                  floating: true,
                  expandedHeight: 180,
                  flexibleSpace: //some widgets
             )
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `elevation` property to `0`.

```
 SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text('Applying to this job opportunity'),
                  pinned: true,
                  elevation: 0,
                  titleSpacing: 0,
                  floating: true,
                  expandedHeight: 180,
                  flexibleSpace: //some widgets
             )
```

More info : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/elevation.html

Comment: hey, I found that the issue was shown just in the emulator and in device worked correctly. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I came here wondering how to remove the shadow, but keep the border. The answer is:

#### Set `elevation` of `SliverAppBar` to `1`

```
SliverAppBar(
  elevation: 1,
  // ...
)
```

Result:

[image: flutter app bar show bottom border without shadow]

Answer (score 1):

It is a long lasting and annoying issue for flutter for ages if you have two slivers are in same color.

The current best walkaround is here (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37578#issuecomment-640302364) by adding a shadow box around your slivers.

You have to try which sliver is best to add the box shadow and how the shadow is added.

Mine is in this way such that it fills the line both on top and at the bottom of the sliver.

```
boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: myColor,
    blurRadius: 0.0,
    spreadRadius: 1.0,
    offset: Offset(0, 0),
   ),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

From my side, the bottom border still displays. It's related to this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16262

So I must set the Background of the Scaffold same the background of the child widgets to fix this issue.

It seems happened only on some phones.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16262#issuecomment-379071933

> If you enclose the Scaffold's body in a SizedBox.expand widget, the
> body will always fill the remaining space. Then, as you pointed out,
> specifying the Scaffold's backgroundColor, hides the problem.

-> Got issue

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                snap: false,
                floating: false,
                elevation: 0.0, // Remove AppBar bottom border
                leading: new Container(),
                titleSpacing: 0,
                expandedHeight: 100.0,
                flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                      top = constraints.biggest.height;
                      return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        centerTitle: true,
                        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: top >= 86
                            ? null
                            : topToolBarWidget(),
                        background: sliverBackgroundWidget()
                      );
                    })),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  PromotionSlider()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

[image]

-> Fixed by adding the Background

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: appPrimaryColor, // <---- add here
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                snap: false,
                floating: false,
                elevation: 0.0, // Remove AppBar bottom border
                leading: new Container(),
                titleSpacing: 0,
                expandedHeight: 100.0,
                flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                      top = constraints.biggest.height;
                      return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        centerTitle: true,
                        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: top >= 86
                            ? null
                            : topToolBarWidget(),
                        background: sliverBackgroundWidget()
                      );
                    })),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  PromotionSlider()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [ltk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787650/12979518) said, you can add shadow. I just show you example with SliverAppBar that worked for me. Elevation should be 0 or null as well.

```
                  SliverAppBar(
                      bottom: PreferredSize(
                          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    blurRadius: 0.0,
                                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: ...))
```